# Xcode Simulators Missing After Installing Beta?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I installed xcode beta as I wanted to push an app to my iphone on 10.1 beta, so needed xcode beta.

The xcode beta is being super flakey and I wanted to go back to xcode 8 current build. However now all the emulators have vanished from the list near the play button.

If i go to Window - Devices, they are all still listed as you would expect...

So i cant see why theyve hidden themselves from view/use, but I cant get them back!

Cheers for any help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your iOS deployment target. It might be that you're app is set to run on iOS 10.1, but you only have sims for iOS 10.

Go to your project file and change deployment target, to for example - iOS 10.

Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

While you can have multiple copies of Xcode installed at the same time, you cannot run them concurrently.  The last one to launch is the one that will be able to use the simulator services.

You should quit your Xcode 8 and then relaunch it.

Also note that if you open Console.app from macOS Sierra, it will use the simulator services from whatever Xcode is selected via xcode-select.  If that doesn’t match your running Xcode, you’ll loose simulator services when opening Console.app.

Answer (score 0):

Check `xcode-select -p`.

If it says `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/`, then simply run `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`. All your simulators will be back in your non-beta Xcode.